# PHP Search Generates Error

Tags: php, mysql, search, mysqli, sql-like

I have a search field feature on my website, with below PHP code:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_ti']) && $_GET['search_ti'] != "")
{
    $search_ti = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!-]#i', '', $_GET['search_ti']);

    $sqlCommand = "
    SELECT * FROM page WHERE title LIKE '%$search_ti%' OR body LIKE '%$search_ti%'
    ";

    $result = $mysqli->query($sqlCommand) or die(mysql_error());
    ...
```

The URL variable `search_ti` is the keyword for the search, which I got from the URL. For example:

```
searchResult.php?search_ti=home
```

If the keyword is found in my MySQL table, the result shows and no errors.

But if the keyword is not found, the web browser generates below error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '-4,4' at line 1
```

What is wrong with my code?

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**

The complete PHP code: http://jsfiddle.net/eQSZc/

The keyword: home. The error only shows if the keyword is not found in my table.

Comment: We need more of your code... Whats on line 1?

Comment: Can you please paste the query in your question which is throwing an error?

Comment: The error appears to be regarding a different query.  The fragment "-4,4" does not appear in the code you have here.

Comment: have you tried echo $sqlCommand; exit; and see what query it generates?

Comment: What a keyword? Does it have some special char? I noticed you didn't check or quete the input data.

Comment: The complete PHP code: http://jsfiddle.net/eQSZc/

Comment: The query that throws error: searchResult.php?search_ti=home

Comment: Yes, the fragment "-4,4" does not exist in my code or my query. I just key in simple keyword like "home", then the error appears. This does not happen if the keyword is found in my table

Comment: I've tried "echo $sqlCommand; exit;", with "home" as the keyword. The web browser shows: SELECT * FROM page WHERE title LIKE '%home%' OR body LIKE '%home%'

Comment: Looks like when there is no resluts your php is executing some other query before it dies. What is in ur `pagination_mechanism_and_buttons_variables_for_Search.php` (Crazy name lol )?

Comment: This is what is inside "pagination_mechanism_and_buttons_variables_for_Search.php": http://jsfiddle.net/GsNmw/. I know it is silly name, I'm not pro PHP programmer :D

Comment: Added a pastie version http://pastie.org/4705905 color coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `pagination_mechanism_and_buttons_variables_for_Search.php` to the one in http://jsfiddle.net/GsNmw/1/

I have added the following block just before you construct the `$limit` and change the `$limit` as well.

```
$start = ($pn - 1) * $itemsPerPage;

if($start<0){
    $start = 0;
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .$start .',' .$itemsPerPage;
```

This avoids negative limit and hence avoids your error.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for this is to use **[`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)**.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
$keyword = '%' . search_ti . '%';
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * 
                       FROM page 
                       WHERE title LIKE ? OR 
                             body LIKE ?");
$stmt->bindParam(1, $name);
if ($stmt->execute())
{
  while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
  {
    print_r($row);
  }
}
?>
```

This will allow you to select records with single quotes.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand how to convert my code into PDO. I'll try to study it later